# The construction of the Long Line topology

Tags: general-topology

The Long line topology is constructed from the ordinal space $[o,\omega_1)$ ( where $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal) by placing between each ordinal $\alpha$ and its successor $\alpha + 1$ a copy of the unit interval $I=(0,1)$. But in the Engelking's book, the Long Line topology defined on the set $V_{0}=W_{0}\times [0,1)$ where $ W_{0}$ is the set of all countable ordinal numbers. But why these are different ? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the most usual formulation of set theory, $\omega_1$ *is* the set of all countable ordinals; so the two definitions of the long line are equivalent.

Squeezing an interval between each countable ordinal is equivalent to turning each countable ordinal into a half-open interval, and the set you get is the union of $\omega_1$-many disjoint half-open intervals, which is essentially the same as your set $V_0$.

Comment: I think that we can not write this space as a disjoint union of two nonempty subsets. But, is there any dense subset of the long line topology?

Comment: Just commenting to add that Engelking's text is completely agnostic about what ordinal numbers actually are, whereas in set theory we have generally decided that ordinal numbers are _von Neumann ordinals_. Because of this agnosticism, Engelking must use different notations for the set of all countable ordinals and the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$.

Comment: @ghb: You can't write it as the disjoint union of two nonempty sub*spaces*; you can write any space (or set) with more than one element as a disjoint union of two nonempty sub*sets*.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Sure. What's important is that the cardinalities of the two sets are the same, and they both have a natural well-ordering of length $\omega_1$.

Comment: Is there any dense subsets?  Can I take the real line as a uncountable ordered space?

Comment: @ghb: Every space has dense subsets (e.g. the space itself). There can be no countable dense subsets, because a countable subset must be 'bounded' in the long line. The real line is an uncountable ordered space, yes, but it has different properties.

Comment: of course, every space itself is dense. But I meant that is there any proper dense subset in the long line?

Comment: @ghb: Yes, e.g. remove a single point.